# Reading data from JavaScript updated html

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, data-structures, finance

Is it possible to read the realtime updated quotes in [this website](http://www.fxstreet.com/technical/currencies-glance/pair.aspx?id=EUR/USD) through actionscript3, without having to reload the page all the time, which would be network-heavy.

In other words, is it possible to stream the quote-data directly into actionscript3 or eventually PHP from javascript?

If not does anyone have any suggestion to how to get these quotes into actionscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on what Theo Said...
(I'm sure there is a much slicker way to do it and I'll be denounced as a hack but it works damnit)

I'm essentially just extracting the first two numbers under the EUR/USD in red.

Here's the php script to put on your server called getContent.php

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("getVars.php", "r");

$contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
     $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}

$vars = explode("&",  $contents);
$time = substr($vars[2], 5);
$difference = abs(date(s)-$time);

if($difference>5)
{

    $handle = fopen("http://www.fxstreet.com/technical/currencies-glance/pair.aspx?id=EUR/USD", "r");

    $contents = '';
        while (!feof($handle)) {
         $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }

    $contents=trim($contents);
    $pos1 = strpos($contents, 'lhtml_0" innerOnUpdate="att=BID" innerfilter="format_number">');
    $str1 = substr($contents, $pos1, 100);
    $cur1 =  substr($str1, 61, 6); 
    $pos2 = strpos($contents, 'lhtml_1" innerOnUpdate="att=ASK" innerfilter="format_number">');
    $str2 = substr($contents, $pos2, 100);
    $cur2 = substr($str2, 61, 6); 

    $cachedPage = fopen("getVars.php", "w");
    $varString = "cur1=$cur1&cur2=$cur2&time=".date(s);
    fwrite($cachedPage,$varString);
    fclose($cachedPage);
    echo "cur1=$cur1&cur2=$cur2&cached=false";
}
else
{
    $handle = fopen("getVars.php", "r");

    $contents = '';
        while (!feof($handle)) {
         $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }

    echo $contents."&cached=true";
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

And then the actionscript

```
var updateTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000);
updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, getQuotes);
updateTimer.start();
function getQuotes(e:Event):void
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("getContent.php");     
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.load(request);
}

function onComplete (event:Event):void
{
   var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
   currency1.text = variables.cur1;
   currency2.text = variables.cur2;
}
var e:Event;
getQuotes(e);
```

You can see it in action here... http://www.hupcapstudios.com/getCurrency.swf

The hack part was my parsing of the page in php.  I had to do some serious substring action.  I'm sure anyone with a decent amount of parsing ability could write a cleaner code for extracting all the data you need.

I just thought I'd take a swing at it.  Good luck :)

Comment: That's cool, but still I guess it's a good idea to not reparse it on each request (unless you handle this with server cache). Imagine a figure : 200 users connects for 60 seconds, that makes 2400 requests (unavoidable) + 2400 fopen/parsing (that hurts). You could make this last number 12 by caching the result (or even less if you use a "lazy" method).

Comment: Good call!  I've just updated the php to only reload and reparse the URL with the content if the time between visits is more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

maybe create a server side script checking the content of the site every 5 seconds or so.
The script could parse out a "cached" version of the "quote" your looking to retrieve. Then just request this cached content via URLRequests at short intervals from your flash application.